# Power BI - Natural Query Language on direct connection

Tags: nlp, powerbi

Is it possible to intercept the SQL message between Power BI Ask a Question front end and back end? In order to control the answers that are presented in visualisations, so that small numbers are always suppressed? This is in the health setting where privacy is important.

For example, the NQL question: "how many patients were admitted by ward on xx/xx/2017?" will produce a bar chart showing record count by ward. If any of the values are less than 5, I want to be able to suppress that value by rounding it up to 5.

I have tried a custom measure (let's call it "admissions"), but that is only invoked if the user specifically uses the name of the measure in the query. So, "total admissions by ward..." works ok, but if the word admissions is left out, then it just shows a record count ("total by ward...")

Comment: What is the question? What have you tried. You need to provide some code or more detail.

Comment: thanks - have edited the question.